# Is there a way to use class method in a module without extend it in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, class, oop

currently I have a module like this:

```
module MyModule
  def A

  end

  .....

end
```

and I have a model that I want to use that method A as a class method. However, the thing is I only need that A method. If I extend it, I am gonna extend the other unnecessary class methods into my model. Therefore, is there a way for me to do sth like MyModule.A without rewriting the module like this:

```
module MyModule
  def A
    ...
  end

  def self.A
    ...
  end

  .....

end
```

It is kind of repeating myself if I do it that way. I still feel there is a better way to do it in Rails.

Comment: [`module_function :A`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-module_function) :: _Sidenote:_ you should not call methods capitalized; there is nothing preventing you of doing so, but ruby has a convention to use capitalized names for very specific cases, like `Kernel#Integer` and family.

Comment: Cold you please re-answer my question as a separate post so I can accept your answer?

Comment: `extend` only brings in the module's instance methods (yes, that is what they are called, even though modules don't have instances) as class methods. `extend` does nothing with the module's class methods (nor does `include`). Therefore, if  `A` (let's call it `a`) is the module's only instance method, there's nothing to do.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use [`Module#module_function`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Module.html#method-i-module_function) to make a single function to be a module function:

```
module M
  def m1; puts "m1"; end
  def m2; puts "m2"; end
  module_function :m2
end
```

or:

```
module M
  def m1; puts "m1"; end
module_function # from now on all functions are defined as module_functions
  def m2; puts "m2"; end
end

M.m1 #⇒ NoMethodError: undefined method `m1' for M:Module
M.m2 #⇒ "m2"
```

Comment: `module_function` is a great find. It's particularly useful because I'll often have modules that *only* have "module_functions" so I just plop `module_function` at the top of the module and all the methods defined are accessed at the class level with having to use `module_function` or `self.` individually. Nice one.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter if you need a static module that defines class methods only, you’d better use `class << self ... end` around the methods, since `module_function` makes an instance method to be doubled as a class method as well, _leaving_ an instance method inplace. It’s basically the same as `extend self` in the very end of the module definition.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can define it as a **module_function**, then you should be able to access it using module name.

Ex:

```
module Mod
  def my_method
    100
  end

  def self.my_method_1
    200
  end
  module_function :my_method
end

Mod.my_method
# => 100
Mod.my_method_1
# => 200
```

Note: No need to add the **self defined methods in module_function**, they are accessible directly. But it's needed for **methods defined without self**